# This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

hello I've been struggling with this error since yesterday, I need some help
here is my middleware and here my route.
This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user->hasAnyRole('school')) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        } else {
            return redirect('login'); 
        }
    }
```

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about')->name('about');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/school', 'HomeController@index')->name('school')->middleware('school');
```

It's even impossible to access the landing page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just to detect the problem can you temporary remove ``` else {
      return redirect('login'); 
    } ``` in middleware check if still have this issue or not

Comment: I removed it and I got this instead Error
Call to a member function send() on null

Comment: Does the `/` route work?

Comment: no I used it whithout /

Comment: You have to check which block causes your redirect, use `dd()` for this

Comment: I mean does the route `Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');` work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
public function __construct(){
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user->hasAnyRole('school')) {
                return $next($request);
            }
            else{
                // Another redirect
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did use it and it didn't work either. In fact wherever I redirect I have the same error

Comment: I tried it and I got this. Call to undefined method App\Http\Middleware\School::middleware() @A.A

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the user again in the else of `hasAnyRole` function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->hasAnyRole('school')) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            // HERE
            return redirect('login'); 
        }
    } else {
        return redirect('login'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried again to redirect them to the other middleware, and still the same. ``` if (!Auth::check()) {
      return redirect()->route('login');
      }

     $user = Auth::user();

     if($user->hasAnyRole('school'))
     {
        return $next($request);
     }
    
     $destinations = ['student','teacher'];

     foreach($destinations as $destination){

       return redirect(route( $user->hasAnyrole($destination)));
     }```