# Shopify API node js causing too many redirects

Tags: node.js, redirect, shopify, shopify-api-node

again I'm following the directions here at https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/docs/getting_started.md to try to spin up a super simple app.

When I hit `localhost:3000` I'm getting a too many redirects error.

The code is below:

```
// src/index.ts
import http from 'http';
import url from 'url';
import querystring from 'querystring';
import Shopify, { ApiVersion, AuthQuery } from '@shopify/shopify-api';
require('dotenv').config();

const { API_KEY, API_SECRET_KEY, SCOPES, SHOP, HOST } = process.env

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY,
  SCOPES: [SCOPES],
  HOST_NAME: HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, ""),
  HOST_SCHEME: HOST.split("://")[0],
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: true,
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October21 // all supported versions are available, as well as "unstable" and "unversioned"
});

// Storing the currently active shops in memory will force them to re-login when your server restarts. You should
// persist this object in your app.
const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS: { [key: string]: string | undefined } = {};

async function onRequest(
    request: http.IncomingMessage,
    response: http.ServerResponse,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const {headers, url: req_url} = request;
    const pathName: string | null = url.parse(req_url).pathname;
    const queryString: string = String(url.parse(req_url).query);
    const query: Record<string, any> = querystring.parse(queryString);
  
    switch (pathName) {
      default:
        // This shop hasn't been seen yet, go through OAuth to create a session
        if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[SHOP] === undefined) {
          // not logged in, redirect to login
          response.writeHead(302, {Location: `/login`});
          response.end();
        } else {
          response.write('Hello world!');
          // Load your app skeleton page with App Bridge, and do something amazing!
        }
        return;
    } // end of default path
  } // end of onRequest()
  
  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

I'm not sure what to do or how to debug this, I looked up too many redirects problems on here but they dont fit in this context

[The localhost page isn’t working. localhost redirected you too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055411/the-localhost-page-isn-t-working-localhost-redirected-you-too-many-times)

[This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501287/this-page-isn-t-working-localhost-redirected-you-too-many-times-try-clearing-yo)

HOw do I fix this in the context of the shopify api?

Comment: I haven't used the new setup but if I remember correctly you shouldn't access the localhost url, but the ngrok one. So instead of `localhost:3000` you should go to `UNIQUE_STRING.ngrok.io`

Comment: I tried that but I still get too many redirects